# Page transition with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, transition

I want to add Full Page Transition to my project to look like Single Page Application, but I'm stuck.

I tried a lot of things with transform: `translateX` and `transition` and `display: none`, but it doesn't work properly as I want..

```js
var firstDiv = document.querySelector('#first'),
    secondDiv = document.querySelector('#second'),
    transitionBtn = document.querySelector('#transitionBtn');

function myFunction() {
    firstDiv.classList.remove('active');
    secondDiv.classList.add('active');
}

transitionBtn.addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  background-color: red;
}

#second {  
  background-color: blue;
}

.page{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  display: none;
  transition: ease-in-out 2s all;
}

.page.active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="first" class="page active">
    <button id="transitionBtn">Click me to transition</button>
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="page"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? The demo seems to work fine.

Comment: First page should dissapear with display: none and second page should appear, but now we can't even see it.

Comment: I see that in `myfunction()`, you removed class named `active` from both divs, but you didn't add it again to any of them ! Or I am wrong ?

Comment: Shady Boshra, it was a mistake when I copied it, my bad, but even with this firstDiv still is visble after transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you wish have no scroll visible, in order to create exit effect ?! if yes, then "overflow: hidden" on body tag helps =)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var firstDiv = document.querySelector('#first'),
    secondDiv = document.querySelector('#second'),
    transitionBtn = document.querySelector('#transitionBtn');

function myFunction() {
    firstDiv.classList.remove('active');
    secondDiv.classList.add('active');
}

transitionBtn.addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}
#first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}

#second {  
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.page{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: ease-in-out 2s all;
  position:absolute;
}

.page.active {
  transform: translateX(0%) !important;
  display: flex !important;
}
```

```html
 <div id="first" class="page active">
    <button id="transitionBtn">Click me to transition</button>
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="page"></div>
```